# Implementing jstree library with Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, static-resources, lwc-dom

This will be a long one, hoping someone can help.

Problem Summary: I'm unable to integrate the "Drag and Drop" (dnd) plugin functionality with my LWC that utilises the jstree library (https://www.jstree.com/).

Detailed description: I have an LWC that is importing the jstree an jquery libraries via static resource to use for a "File Explorer" feature in Salesforce - this is based on the source code published by Q Labs team at Salesforce Labs here: https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/FileExplorer
This tool provides a great user experience for uploading, organising and searching for files with a familiar "windows" style structure - see screenshot:

[image]

Currently, users have the ability to move files and folders using the context menus - which works well, but drag and drop would add that next level of useability, so that's what I'm trying to do.

The code:
I've edited the files below to what I think are the relevant parts, as there is quite a lot of code - happy to share the full code if it helps:

fileTree.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" vertical-align="stretch">
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small">
            <div class="tree-home" onclick={handleHomeClick}>
                <img class="slds-m-left_xx-small" src="https://test.com/images/tree_folder.png">
                <span class=slds-p-left_small>{CONSTANTS.TREE_LABELS.HOME}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="jstree slds-p-top_xxx-small" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

fileTree.js

```
import {LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import {loadScript, loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import jquery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jquery_350';
import jstree from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jstree_339';
import jstree339 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jstree339';

export default class FileTree extends LightningElement {
    /**
     * Enumerations
     */
    JSTREE_ACTIONS = {
        'SELECT_NODE': 'select_node',
        'SELECT_HOME': 'select_home',
        'DESELECT_ALL': 'deselect_all',
        'MOVE_NODE': 'move_node',
    };

    /**
     * Internal properties
     */
    _error;
    _resourcesLoaded = false;
    _tree;
    _$tree;
    _$treeInstance;
    _selectedItem;

    /**
     * Private properties
     */
    CONSTANTS = CONSTANTS;
    isLoading = true;
    files;
    folders;
    dataDictionary;
    dataTree;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.haveResourcesLoaded) {
            return;
        }

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, jquery),
            loadScript(this, jstree339),
            loadStyle(this, jstree + '/themes/default/style.css'),
        ]).then(() => {
            this.initialiseTree();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    addTreeListeners() {
        this._$tree.on('ready.jstree', this.handleTreeReady.bind(this));
        this._$tree.on('refresh.jstree', this.handleTreeReady.bind(this));
        this._$tree.on('changed.jstree', this.handleTreeChange.bind(this));
        // this is the line I've added to subscribe to the drag and drop functionality
        this._$tree.on('move_node.jstree', this.handleMoveNode.bind(this));
    }

    initialiseTree() {
        this._tree = this.template.querySelector('div.jstree');
        this._$tree = $(this._tree);
        this.bindTree(this.dataTree);
    }

    bindTree(data) {
        if (data) {
            this.addTreeListeners();
            this._$tree.jstree({
                'core': {
                    'data': data,
                    'check_callback': true,
                    'themes': {
                        'responsive': false,
                        'variant': 'large',
                        'stripes': false,
                    },
                },
                
                'plugins': ['sort_ascending_folders_first','dnd'], // I have added the 'dnd' plugin here, as per documentation
                'sort_ascending_folders_first': function (a, b) {
                    let nodeA = this.get_node(a, false);
                    let nodeB = this.get_node(b, false);

                    if (!(nodeA.documentId)) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return (nodeA.text.toLowerCase() >
                            nodeB.text.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1;
                    }
                },
                'lwc_host': this._tree, // I think this is what connects the jstree to the lwc
            });
        } else {
            window.setTimeout((data) => {
                this.bindTree(data);
            }, 1000, this.dataTree);
        }
    }

    handleTreeReady(e, data) {
        this._$treeInstance = this._$tree.jstree(true);
        this.isLoading = false;
        // dispatch custom event - not important here
        );
    }

    handleTreeChange(e, data) {
        this._selectedItem = (data.node && data.node.original)
            ? data.node.original
            : {};
        this.template.querySelector('div.tree-home').classList.remove('item-selected');
        // dispatch custom event - not important here;
    }

    handleMoveNode(e, data) {
        // have never been able to get the below output
        console.log('we have moved');
        console.log(data);
    }

}
```

jstree_399.resource - available here, too big to paste: https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/FileExplorer/blob/master/src/staticresources/jstree_339.resource

My understanding of the above is:

- Component loads resources on render
- The tree component is built with given configuration and 'bound' to the 'jstree' div
- Event listeners are initialised on the LWC that listen for particular events fired from the jstree

And what I'm trying to achieve (without success) is:

- Hook into the 'move_node' event that is part of the 'dnd' plugin in the jstree static resource.

The gaps in my knowledge:

- Is it right to say that the 'lwc:dom="manual"' makes the jstree instance a "child" of the component?
- If you search in the static resource for 'lwc', the previous developer has added a few lines to the jstree file to 'bind' the **lwc_host** to the instance of jstree - what exactly is the nature of this binding? It's a bit beyond my knowledge. It does look like the original developer has attempted to get this drag and drop functionality working (commented out code in the static resource) but I can't interpret what they were trying to do.
- The jstree event listeners that are working (ready.jstree, refresh.jstree, changed.jstree) appear to be part of the 'native' jstree code whereas the 'move_node.jstree' event I'm trying to hook into is part of the 'dnd' plugin - perhaps this is a clue? I have added the 'dnd' plugin to the config (part of 'bindTree' function) and attempted to hook into the move_node event but with no luck so far.
- It does appear that the 'dnd' feature is active once I load the plugin, as you can drag a file and the icons change and looks like it should work - but nothing happens on drop (which is supposedly what 'move_node' should trigger).

Any guidance would be appreciated, I'm not sure where to go from here.